# Why isn't the LaTex preview pane showing the preview in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I recently installed latex preview pane on my emacs. It turned out that it is not showing the proper preview. Instead it shows some random codes as shown in the snapshot. How do I make it show the preview? Please give detailed instructions.
[image]

Comment: Exactly which Emacs version is this? Most Emacs users I know use external previewers when previewing the PDF. Is the showing of PDF directly in Emacs even available on Windows?

Comment: To view your PDFs just take SumatraPDF, reliable and easy to customise.

Comment: Do you have ghost script installed? It is needed.

Comment: Ye, I have ghost script installed. And my Emacs version is 24.4.

Comment: You need certain `*.dll` files to view images in `doc-view` in conjunction with GhostScript.  Did you install those `*.dll` files?   Some builds of Emacs include them, and some do not.  `M-x describe-variable RET dynamic-library-alist RET` for a list of the `*.dll` files needed for your particular version of Emacs -- they go in the `bin` directory of Emacs.  For example, the Emacs version that I am using for Windows has an element of that list as follows:  `(png "libpng16.dll" "libpng16-16.dll")` and those are needed to view `*.png` files (which is what GhostScript uses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supposed it is a problem with `doc-view` on windows. I quote part of my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261665/50058) for the windows part:

- follow the intruction on [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DocViewMode) to install a ps/pdf viewer
- open the ps/pdf produced as any other file. (`C-x C-f file_name.pdf/ps`), `doc-view` mode will be used and you will be able to see the document.